# Zooming functionality in MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, zooming

I try to implement zooming functionality in an MFC application where the objects rendered on the screen are bitmap icons.

I set the zoom level of the view in the `OnMouseWheel` event.

The view class inherits from `CScrollView`.

```
class CMyView : public CScrollView
```

All actions are performed in `OnPrepareDC` function.

```
void CMyView::OnPrepareDC(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
```

first i set the mapping mode to `MM_ANISOTROPIC`

```
pDC->SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
```

Lets say that i want to zoom around the mouse point.

So i keep the coordinates of this point (In device and in logical coordinate system)

```
POINT pt_to_keep;
GetCursorPos(&pt_to_keep); // device coordinates
POINT logical_point_to_keep_focused { pt_to_keep };
pDC->DPtoLP(&logical_point_to_keep_focused); // logocal coordinates
```

Afterwards, the zooming actions are below:

```
CSize sizeTotal = GetDocument()->GetSizeInLogicalUnits();
CSize viewTotalSize = GetTotalSize();

viewTotalSize.cx *= GetDocument()->GetZoomLevel();
viewTotalSize.cy *= GetDocument()->GetZoomLevel();
sizeTotal.cy = -sizeTotal.cy; // the yaxis is negative a the mapping mode is MM_ANISOTROPIC
pDC->SetViewportExt(viewTotalSize); //device units
pDC->SetWindowExt(sizeTotal); //logical units
```

After the Viewport and Window Extends are set, i try to calc the new Window origin in such a way that the previous logical point that was under the mouse point is placed again at the same device point.

```
POINT physical_point_to_keep_focused { logical_point_to_keep_focused };
pDC->LPtoDP(&physical_point_to_keep_focused);
```

The distance of the mouse point from the window origin (in device coordinates)  is equal to the mouse point x and y coordinates (trivial). That is:

```
int dist_x = pt_to_keep.x;
int dist_y = abs(pt_t0_keep.y);
```

On the next step i calculate the new origin point in logical coordinates:

```
POINT physical_viewport_origin { physical_point_to_keep_focused };
physical_viewport_origin.x -= dist_x;
physical_viewport_origin.y -= dist_y;

POINT logical_viewport_origin { physical_viewport_origin };
pDC->DPtoLP(&logical_viewport_origin);
```

And finally set it as the new window origin

```
pDC->SetWindowOrg(logical_viewport_origin);
```

The zooming seems to work in an extend.
But the strangest thing is that after i zoom in (for example)  and i use the scroll to move the view, after i return the scroll to the initial position, the area of the view that was hidden and then redrawn, is shown in the initial zoom factor.
So i end up with a view that is like it shows two images attached to each other and the image on the one side is in zoom level 1,0 and the image on the other side is at zoomlevel (eg) 1.8

I think that the calculation of the logical point that has to be set as the new Window Origin is correct.
I also want to point out that some times the zooming is not very smooth and the view "jumps" from one zoom level to another in a big step.